# Changing order of listview results from SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview in my application that displays records according to the primary key _ID field with the lowest _ID number first. How can I change that so it is the highest _ID number first in the listview? i.e reverse the order.

The db query currently generating the listview is below. Thanks!

```
    public Cursor fetch() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper._ID, DatabaseHelper.SLOC, DatabaseHelper.FLOC, DatabaseHelper.DSNM, DatabaseHelper.SDATE, DatabaseHelper.STIME };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToLast();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: `... ORDER BY _id DESC`

Comment: see the last param of `query` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query:

```
  Cursor c = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, rank, null, null, null, null, yourColumn+" DESC");
```

Comment: Awesome! adding DatabaseHelper._ID+" DESC" works. The system did not recognise "rank" however so I kept it as "columns" in the query. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rawQuery` method to hit any custom query like this and add `ORDER BY` `ASC` or `DESC` as you wish.

```
public Cursor fetch() {

    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY _id DESC"

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(queryString);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToLast();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```